# novigator display code instead of executing it

Tags: php, wampserver

I am trying to write a webpage in php.

I installed wamp64, it has the php7.4 version selected, however when I try to display my page on the navigator it shows the code instead of running it.

I also have the following message when I go on localhost :

> Notice: Undefined index: urlAddLocalhost in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 33

don't know if this is related.

Am I correct to assume that php is downloaded with wamp and apache when I did instaled wamp?

If not how should I proceed ?

Comment: You are getting a PHP Error message,  ipso facto PHP must be running.

Comment: What do you mean by `when I try to display my page on the navigator`

Comment: If you have placed your own code into the `C:\wamp64\www` then you have overwritten the WAMPServer homepage wher you can find all the useful bits and bobs.

Comment: Which version of WAMPServer are you running

Comment: _"when I go on localhost"_ - That's the only way you should open the site. When you say _"on the navigator"_, do you mean that you double click on the PHP file directly? If yes, then that won't work. You must run it through the web server (using localhost). If you double click on it, it won't be run through the web server and the PHP won't be executed.

Comment: This index `urlAddLocalhost` only appears to be used in the translation files. What happens if you switch to English

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, in the end there was a problem with were I placed my wamp files ... problem solved